# The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Tags: android, android-support-library, redpin

i dowloaded from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/redpin/files/release-3.1/RedpinAndroid.zip/download

i am using win8, ECLİPSE eclipse-standard-kepler-SR1-win32

i imported project and googled this problem. I tried project > clean section , it didnt work.
and also i tried properties > java build path > add library > jre system library for adding redpind library , it didnt work either. how can i solve this problem? thank you.

errors is:

**The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved**

**Project 'RedpinAndroid' is missing required Java project: 'RedpinCore'**

[image]
**these are classes**
[image]
**this is properties>buildpath**
[image: enterd image description here]
**this is error page**

Comment: Is there a .classpath file in your project folder? Could you post it?

Comment: Please put some screenshots of your error of your project.

Comment: i cant put screenshoot, i need 11 rep to do it.

Comment: @FD_ deskop/RedpinAndroid

Comment: You have more than 11 rep now ;)

Answer (score 3):

This project depends another project named **RedpinCore**, so in order to build this, you need to reference the place where RedpinCore project resides, so that your project can find needed class definitions. **Instead of this**, you can remove this dependency, and add [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/redpin/files/latest/download) jar to your classpath. The same classes can also be found in this.

Right click on your project Build Path/Configure Build Path...

Under Projects tab, right click on this project dependency and remove it.

Then copy the jar to your project and add it to your classpath.

Comment: thank you. error is gone. but now i had a java heap space error. i am trying to solve this.